# Display very long lines

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to display a file content in a textbox or textblock in WPF. The line length is in excess of 20,000 characters. 
Trying to display the file content with a horizontal scroll bar and display the 20,000 chars in one line without wrapping.

Long lines keep wrapping at around 9000+ char position. File has CRLF line breaks.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
   <TextBlock x:Name="txtFileText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello" FontFamily="Consolas" Background="AliceBlue" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Need Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: use `<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"><anyControl/></ScrollViewer>`

Comment: if performance is too slow then you may want to consider a _binary space-partition_ tree

Answer (score 0):

Set your TextBlock\Box Width and Height properties to "Auto", make sure to set the "TextWrapping" property of the Textblock to "Wrap" and if needed place your Textblock inside a ScrollViewer(right click on your textblock in the "Objects and Timeline" window and pick "Group Into" and pick a ScrollViewer).

Comment: Sorry didn't work. Long lines keep wrapping at around 9000+ char position. File has CRLF line breaks.

<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
   <TextBlock x:Name="txtFileText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello" FontFamily="Consolas" Background="AliceBlue" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
</ScrollViewer>